# Features auto delete field

Tags: 7, entities, features

I've been using Feature to provision changes between my DEV, STAGING and LIVE sites.

What I'm finding is when I make a field redundant on a node type on my DEV site, features does not automatically delete is on my STAGING site.

For example: I originally had a field called **Key Contact** in my Basic Page node type. I created a feature which I uploaded to my STAGING site, the Key Contact field was created and it worked fine.

However, that same field is now redundant. I have deleted it on my DEV site. I re-created the Feature and uploaded to my STAGING site.

**The problem is the Key Contact field still exists on the STAGING version of my website.**

*Can anyone give me some direction to get Features to not just create new fields but remove fields I have deleted on DEV - so I don't have to delete a lot of fields manually on both STAGING and eventually the LIVE site?*

Comment: Features automatically deleting fields seems like an extremely dangerous feature to me, and I think there is good reason for it not to happen. I would probably go about it by deploying update hooks along with the features changes.

Answer (score 1):

As declared in https://www.drupal.org/node/649298#comment-7710069 there won't be any such support in Features module itself. In the same issue, there is also relevant answer in https://www.drupal.org/node/649298#comment-10219951:

> You can instead add a hook_update_N function to a custom module and delete the field with code (see field_delete_field).

This should be used in `my_feature.install` file. Note that if you go this way, you will probably need to add something like

```
function my_feature_features_export_files($module_name, $export) {
  if ($module_name == 'my_feature') {
    return array('my_feature.install' => array('file_path' => 'sites/all/modules/my_feature/my_feature.install'));
  }
}
```

to you `my_feature.module` file. This ensures that `my_feature.install` file is added to feature on any further export.